# Connecting to apache server across town

Tags: apache-http-server

I would like an example , syntax, of an address LINE i would use to connect to my apache server across town. what would it look like.   EXAMPLE:

PUBLIC IP/EXTERNAL IP (IPV4),LOCAL IP,PORT 80
WOULD IT LOOK LIKE THIS ??
00.000.000.000,OOO.000.0.00:80

I am new at this . but  my windows 10 server is running (**IT WORKS**) and i ca access within lan , tested 80 open
Thanks Chuck

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. Please edit your post to tell us exactly what you are asking and the things you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.example.com or http://123.456.789.0 using an address same as any other web server on the planet. Or perhaps https:// starting it if using ssl but then you would have mentioned port 443, so probably not that. If you do not have domain then you need to determine what your public IP is to use it to connect and if the port (80) is being forwarded past any routers or firewalls in place.